# keytool -genkeypair + keytool -list + jarsigner -verify ==>ZipException in java 1.8 win 10

Tags: java, keytool, jarsigner

## Batch file:

```
REM Create a keystore
cd C:\Users\chatt\ChessClockIFACE
del debug.keystore
echo %JAVA_HOME%
DATE /T
TIME /T

keytool -genkeypair -v ^
    -validity 10000 ^
    -keystore debug.keystore ^
    -storepass android ^
    -keypass android ^
    -alias androiddebugkey ^
-dname "CN=Peter Chatterton, OU=Android, O=Chatterton Consulting, L=Hamilton, S=ON, C=CA" ^
    -keyalg RSA

keytool -list -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android

jarsigner -verify debug.keystore

dir debug.keystore
```

References Consulted:

```
-http://geosoft.no/development/android.html
(Building Android programs on the command line)
-Barry Burd's Dummies book p.600.
-Java in a Nutshell v1.5
```

I wanted to annotate the batch file with its output but the question engine said it looked too much like code and wanted 'more details'(?).
Here's most of it as an Edit:

```
HOME>keytool  -genkeypair  -v  -validity 10000  -keystore debug.keystore ^
              -storepass android  -keypass android     -alias androiddebugkey ^
-dname "CN=Peter Chatterton, OU=Android, O=Chatterton Consulting, L=Hamilton, S=ON, C=CA" ^
              -keyalg RSA
Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA256withRSA) with a validity of 10,000 days
        for: CN=Peter Chatterton, OU=Android, O=Chatterton Consulting, L=Hamilton, ST=ON, C=CA
[Storing debug.keystore]

HOME>keytool -list -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN
Your keystore contains 1 entry
androiddebugkey, 24-Jan-2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 24:FC:1C:74:97:42:8C:D4:5F:E9:0A:DD:6C:64:D2:9F:2E:00:6D:23

HOME>jarsigner -verify debug.keystore
jarsigner: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"jarsigner -verify" is used to verify the signature of a JAR file, like this:

```
jarsigner -verify application.jar
```

It isn't used to verify the integrity of a keystore, which looks like it's what you're trying to do.

Can you give more information about what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to sign a JAR file, verify one, or something else?

If you just want to check that the keystore file is ok, the "keytool -list" command that you already have should do that. If there's anything wrong with the keystore it would give an error at that point.

Comment: I've had exactly the same problem again (except with apksigner) and I realize that I didn't acknowledge your spot-on solution to my question, I think I worried too much about the bureaucratic crap about comment usage.  Anyway: thank you very much for your help.